# How to sum 2 Sine Wave?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I've this function in mine script that creates 2 sines wave.

```
f_sine_wave(_wave_height, _wave_duration) =>
  _pi = 3.14159265359
  _w = 2 * _pi / _wave_duration
  _sine_wave = _wave_height * math.sin(_w * bar_index)
  _sine_wave
```

Here an image of plotting

[image: Plotting from Pinescript Indicator]

What i would like to do is sum them and get an average of them, maybe an image explain better then me.

[image: Line Blue is what im trying to get]

i tried to simply sum and the divide by two `(sine1 + sine2) / 2` but dont works as i expect.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you give us an example of how you are using this function and plotting the output? It looks fine on my end.

Comment: For creating the output i was using the function, in this way:
avg_wave = f_sine_wave(100, wave_1 + wave_2) and then plotting on chart. instaed the correct solution was avg_wave = (wave_1 + wave_2) / 2 without calling the function. My mistake ouch ahah Thank you as alwasy Vitruvius! You're always helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign first and second sin waves to a variable and get the average of those.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

f_sine_wave(_wave_height, _wave_duration) =>
    _pi = 3.14159265359
    _w = 2 * _pi / _wave_duration
    _sine_wave = _wave_height * math.sin(_w * bar_index)

sin1 = f_sine_wave(9, 30)
sin2 = f_sine_wave(3, 10)
sin3 = (sin1 + sin2) / 2

plot(sin1, color=color.green)
plot(sin2, color=color.red)
plot(sin3, color=color.yellow)
hline(0)
```

[image]